# Change the div's in another html page

Tags: javascript, html

still learning some javascript here, got done other things but now the final and most important part of it.

I have two html pages - one of which uses javascript to dynamically add text-fields (and to remove them of course) (genmain.html) and the other one where the text field input should go(table.html).

So i have already created a function to retrieve the array of values.

```
function getElementArray(divName){
   var names = document.getElementsByName("namefield");
}
```

The variable names is an array and it has all the values from fields.

The problem is I would like to set these values from array to the values of another div on the page. After some searching i understood that it could be done with 'id'-s but i'm not that sure and don't completely understand how.

Let's say i have a lot of div's on another page (table.html) but some of them have id="MAIN". I would like to change the value inside of the div

For example

```
<div id="MAIN">THIS PART I WANT TO CHANGE</div>
```

Javascript is not part of my school system and i've done CodeAcademy tutorials and that's the most i've got about this, I hope you guys can help with my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The variable names is an array and it has all the values from fields.

```
function getElementArray(divName){
   var names = document.getElementsByName("namefield");
}
```

Nope, you've only got reference to the elements here. You've not got the value yet.

You can get the values by iterating through the names Nodelist array and use `names[i].value`

> The problem is I would like to set these values from array to the
>   values of another div on the page

If it's going to be in same page, then use `innerHTML` or `textContent` property of the DOM to assign the value.

```
document.getElementById("MAIN").textContent= names[1].value;
```

Just for demo purpose am using `names[1]` here so it will load the second input value.

> Let's say i have a lot of div's on another page (table.html) but some
>   of them have id="MAIN". I would like to change the value inside of the
>   div

Once you move to another page, the javascript state will be lost. So you wont have access to `names` inside that page.

Either you must store the values into localStorage and retrieve in next page.

Else add the values to `query` string of your URL and retrive it there.

> Edit: Update based on comments

Let us assume you have `var names = document.getElementsByName("namefield");` so to store the values inside localStorage.

```
var myValues = [],
    names = document.getElementsByName("namefield");
    for(var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        myValues.push(names[i].value);
    } 
    localStorage.myValues = JSON.stringify(myValues);
```

Now if your next page, Iinside `window.onload` event:

```
   window.onload = function() {
       var myValues = localStorage.getItem("myValues") ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("myValues")) : [],
           divElements = document.querySelectorAll("#MAIN");
       for(var i =0; i < myValues.length; i++) {
           divElements[i].textContent = myValues[i];
       }
   }
```

Comment: How could i store the values into localstorage? Could you give a brief example in an edit and how to retrieve it in a next page aswell.

Comment: I will try this when i'll get home and report back, thanks for now, if any issues i'll comment..

Comment: Just a dummy follow up question, how should i call out the window.onload event in the next page? I added the function in onload.js and called out the script in html head, is this enough?

Comment: You need not call the event. Browser will trigger the event. Yes that's enough

Comment: Thanks, that's how to do it, i'll hope it will help someone else aswell. Marked as answer!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set or change the contents of an element, you can use the `innerHTML` property.

So in your case, `document.getElementById("MAIN").innerHTML = "Whatever you want";`

For the record, `names` in your example technically isn't an array, but a `NodeList`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeList#Why_is_NodeList_not_an_Array.3F.

Comment: yes, but how could i refer it to another page? Function is called out on a button click in genmain.html but the element is in table.html.

Comment: There's no way you can set the contents of one web page from another. You can pull a same-origin web page into your javascript using Ajax, but that's different.